# Select the current row of GridView not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I want to select the current row of GridView

```
int i = 0; 
    int a1, a2,a3;
    string ida = Session["id"].ToString();
    foreach (GridViewRow gv in grdreport.Rows)
    {
    Label id = (Label)grdreport.Rows[i].Cells[6].FindControl("lblid");
    Label lblqus = (Label)grdreport.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("Label1"); ;
    Label lblans = (Label)grdreport.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("Label2");
    try //geting Officer ID
    {
        int j = 0;
        DataTable dtofc = new DataTable();
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_FAQ_CCA", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("qryflg", "Officer1");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dtofc);
        officerDept = dtofc.Rows[j]["DeptId"].ToString();
        QAId = dtofc.Rows[j]["QAId"].ToString();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

It only selects the first row of GridView even though I click on 2nd row.
I also tried this :

```
Label id = (Label)grdreport.currentrow.cell[6].FindControl("lblid");
Label id = (Label)gv.FindControl("lblid");
```

but it's not working as well, Please help me with this.

Comment: the code is inside rowcommand event handler?

Comment: How you select the row(by clicking checkbox or button?)

Comment: Post your full function not only the inner code.

Comment: by clicking on link button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
 Label id = (Label)gv.Cells[6].FindControl("lblid");
    Label lblqus = (Label)gv.Cells[3].FindControl("Label1"); 
    Label lblans = (Label)gv.Cells[4].FindControl("Label2");
```

If you want it inside a button click event handler:

```
 protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //clicked button
        LinkButton btn= (LinkButton)sender;

        // row of the clicked button
        GridViewRow containerRow = (GridViewRow)(btn).NamingContainer;

    Label id = (Label)containerRow .Cells[6].FindControl("lblid");
    Label lblqus = (Label)containerRow .Cells[3].FindControl("Label1"); 
    Label lblans = (Label)containerRow .Cells[4].FindControl("Label2");

 /// remaining code

}
```

Comment: sir its in linkbuttons click event